# What's the right way to run a second pass shader in XNA?

Tags: 3d, xna, shader

In XNA 4.0 what's the right way to set up a "second pass" shader where I want to take a frame that's been rendered and then run the entire rendered screen through a shader program?

Is it possible to run a third pass as well?

Comment: Are you talking about having a second pass in the shader itself?

Comment: Here's a related article that you and readers of your question might find interesting: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/08/17/combining-shaders.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. you need to render the scene on a RenderTarget2D and then render the texture on device using your pixel shader.

```
RenderTarget2D target; // needs to instanciate in LoadContent();
Effect myEffect; // this one too.
Draw(GameTime gametime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(target);
    RenderScene();
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    myEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

    spriteBatch.Draw( .... , target, ...);
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```